# django filter icontains match whole words only

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am using the filter icontains to search for words but I only want it to match whole words.  e.g. if I searched for liver I wouldn't want it returning delivery.

my query looks like this

```
MyModel.objects.filter(title__icontains=search_word)
```

I have seen the filter `__search` but this does not bring back results with 3 characters or less and the site I am building contains a lot of these which could be searched for, e.g. 'bbc'

I do not have access to the db but if anyone knows how I can disable this in the code then I would be happy to switch to using this as an alternative.

Comment: Perhaps you could use [regex](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iregex) instead, or add spaces at start and end of your `search_word` string?

Comment: I was thinking about adding spaces but if the title was only 1 word or the word appeared at the beginning or end of the title then this would not work.  How would I do it via regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regexp are usually enough :
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex

Please note that the regular expression syntax is that of the **database backend in use**.

In python (sqlite) the regexp would be :

```
\b(word)\b
```

In Mysql you have :

```
mysql> SELECT 'a word a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';   -> 1
mysql> SELECT 'a xword a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';  -> 0
```

Comment: this along with http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iregex solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In case you have [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) and REST service implemented with [tastypie](/questions/tagged/tastypie) or DRF, you can filter by whole words as `$http.get(uri, {'params': {'display_name__iregex': '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]'})`

of course, `display_name` should be enabled to filtering in Tastypie resource's Meta class as `filtering = {'display_name': ALL,}`

Answer (score -3):

It sounds like you want a Case-insensitive exact match.

```
MyModel.objects.filter(title__iexact=search_word)
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lookup-iexact

Comment: this would not work as I still want to search for part of a string but iexact requires the whole string to match.  for example if my title was 'this is a test title'  I would want to find this if I searched for 'test title'

Comment: I see.  You want it to find 'test title' but not 'est title'.  Got it.