# Whole-word match only in Django query

Tags: regex, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am trying to write a Django query that will only match whole words.  Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4024355/1256700), I've tried something like:

```
result = Model.objects.filter(text__iregex='\bsomeWord\b')
```

But this isn't returning the expected result.  I also tried

```
result = Model.objects.filter(text__iregex=r'\bsomeWord\b')
```

to no avail.  My end goal is to be able to pass in a string variable as well, something like:

```
result = Model.objects.filter(text__iregex=r'\b'+stringVariable+r'\b')
```

or

```
result = Model.objects.filter(text__iregex=r'\b %s \b'%stringVariable)
```

But right now I can't even get it to work with a raw string.  I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use “**\y**” instead of “**\b**” when you're using PostgreSQL, this is because Django passes your regular expression straight down to PostgreSQL – so your RegEx's need to be compatible with it. You should be able to execute them from `psql` without any problems.

```
result = Model.objects.filter(text__iregex=r"\y{0}\y".format(stringVariable))
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE

Comment: Django doesn't do any translating of PCREs to PostgreSQL regular expressions (see: http://bit.ly/ZtpbgH). So you just have to use PostgreSQL's native regular expressions, see here: http://bit.ly/ZtpojU

Comment: This works.  Thanks for adding the explanation about `\y` as well.  As for the `'{0}'.format(stringVariable)` part, is that just another way of writing `'%s'%stringVariable`?  Both seem to work for me.

Comment: Yeah, effectively they both do the same. I just use the `.format()` way because Python 3 requires it (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get something by dropping the regex and using a few django lookups

```
result = Model.objects.filter(Q(text__contains=' someword ') |
                              Q(text__contains=' someword.') |
                              Q(text__istartswith = 'someword.' |
                              Q(text__istartswith = 'someword.' |
                              Q(text__iendswith = 'someword')
```

see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/) for docs.

I realize that's not so elegant (but makes for easy maintenance if you're not a fan of regex).

Comment: Because this doesn't perform a whole-word match; for instance, if I do a `text__contains='tart'` I pick up results like `start`.

Comment: my bad - I'm obviously not familiar with sql enough to know that 'whole word match' meant something specific. Anyway, I've updated my answer to improve it a bit.

Comment: Easy maintenance? There are lots of cases you're not covering there (between `()`, commas, etc).

Comment: Easy maintenance if you're not a fan of regex. You don't need to know django or python to read this - but I'd have to reference any regex that solves this problem. And yes, this doesn't catch everything - It would only work if you're confident that text contains only a subset of the language.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to match word boundaries using the Perl-compatible escape sequence \b.  My backend database is MySQL.

I solved the problem by the character class expression [[:space:]], e.g.

```
        q_sum = Q()
        search_list = self.form.cleaned_data['search_all'].split(' ');
        for search_item in search_list:
            search_regex = r"[[:space:]]%s[[:space:]]" % search_item
            q_sum |= Q(message__iregex=search_regex)
        queryset = BlogMessages.objects.filter(q_sum).distinct()
```

Comment: This won't account for punctuation just so you know.