# 'Q' object has no attribute 'split' - Django

Tags: python, django, django-q

I have a Model:

```
class Authors(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()
   person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

and query:

```
authors = Author.objects.filter(
                                (Q(name__iregex=r"\y{0}\y".format(s1)),
                                ~Q(name__iregex=r"\y{0}\y".format(s2))
                                ),
                                person=None).order_by('-id')
```

I am getting the error:

```
'Q' object has no attribute 'split'
```

why is this? i am not using `split()` though.. the line of error is in this query line.

Comment: What does `\y` match? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @frnhr matches only whole words and not part of words.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14998059/903790

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to join your `Q()` filters with a logical operator like `|` or `&`.

```
authors = Author.objects.filter(
                                (Q(name__iregex=r"\y{0}\y".format(s1)) &
                                ~Q(name__iregex=r"\y{0}\y".format(s2))
                                ),
                                person=None).order_by('-id')
```

Comment: i thought, ``,`` stays for ``&``, doesnot it?

Comment: I think because you have the `Q()` objects wrapped in a paren, you need to use `&` explicitly. I.e, you have `filter( (Q(), Q()), person=None)`. Does changing to `&` work? I'm not entirely confident about this answer TBH haha

Comment: @Furbeenator https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Thanks, @Sohan Jain. I see they state `Q objects can be combined using the & and | operators. When an operator is used on two Q objects, it yields a new Q object.` but the examples didn't show any `&`s and they are implied with the filter. It would be nice if the docs showed when the explicit `&` is required, rather than have to lookup the "split" error. Thanks again, this got me out of a jam!

Comment: Actually I still don't see clearly when we have to use the explicit and/or notation and when comma separated Q are enough...