# How do I write a Django query that finds words in a Postgres column?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  How do I scan for words in a Django query?  A word is a string surrounded by whitespace (or the beginning or end of a line).  I have this ...

```
def get_articles_with_words_in_titles(self, long_words):
    qset = Article.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(title__icontains=x) for x in long_words)))
    result = set(list(qset))
```

but if "long_words" contains things like ["about", "still"], it will match Articles whose titles have things like "whereabouts" or "stillborn".  Any idea how to modify my query to incorporate word boundaries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whole-word match only in Django query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997536/whole-word-match-only-in-django-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try iregex or regex

```
# Article.objects.filter(title__iregex=r"\y(still|about)\y")
words = "|".join(long_words)
Article.objects.filter(title__iregex=fr"\y({words})\y")
```

This should work for PostgreSQL

Django documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#iregex

Python's regular expression documentation for word boundaries:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#index-26

PostgreSQL's documentation on word boundaries:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE

Comment: if you're using MySQL, according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001111/django-filter-iregex-to-match-complete-word-only you might need to look up MySQL's way of doing word boundaries.

Comment: I'm using PostGres but even so you're statement isn't working.  The query builds things like '"article"."title"::text ~* \\b(canada|woman|properly)\\b' but that isn't returning any results when a hard-coded query like "title like '% canada %'" by itself returns results.

Comment: Hi Dave, I've updated my answer, seems like you need to use the Postgres' regex flavour to define the word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you sure its "\y"?  Python is telling me "Illegal/unsupported escape sequence."

Comment: @Dave yes, I tried it in my app. Django does not translate python regex to Postgres’

Comment: @Dave are u getting a warning in your IDE or is it an exception? If it is an exception, you might need to remove r from before the string, and use `f“\\y({words})\\y”` instead.

Comment: It was my IDE -- PyCharm, but I ignored the IDE errors and just fired things up and things do appear to be working.  Will run a few more tests and then will come back and accept.  Thx!

Answer (score 4):

If you database is postgres, I suggest to try the [`Full Text Search`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-intro.html) of postgres.

And it seems that django has [builtin module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) of it.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchQuery

search_vector = SearchVector('title')
search_query = SearchQuery('about') & SearchQuery('still')

Article.objects.annotate(
  search=search_vector
).filter(
  search=search_query
)
```